# Toolbox like in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, controls

I'd like to add a toolbox that looks like the ones in Visual Studio (Solution Explorer, controls, etc.). Where can I find something like this?

I am using .NET 4, C#, and [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms).

Comment: If you create an MFC app with Visual Studio 2010, this is one of the options you can select in the wizard. You get the entire interface framework for free. I didn't post this as an answer because you didn't specify which language and GUI toolkit that you were developing in. Are we just supposed to assume C# from your gravatar?

Comment: Haha yes you should assume C#. But I'm not using MFC for this specific project at this time. But good to know, I'll check it out.

Comment: Sooo, are you using WinForms or WPF? You can write code in C# for both.

Comment: .Net 4, C#, WinForms - but I've got the message, I've created my own "Toolbox" control. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of places that offer controls and components for sale and for free.  I am assuming you are referring to Managed (.NET) controls.

[Component Factory](http://www.componentfactory.com/windows-forms-products.php) offers a lot of Office 2007 and Visual Studio related controls for free.

[Actipro Software](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/default.aspx) offers expensive but high-end Visual Studio related controls such as toolbars, docking windows and syntax highlighting.[image: Activepro Software controls]

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at Component Factory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really find something like that - rather, you make it. The Solution Explorer is a TreeView, and the Toolbox is a custom control with drag and drop implemented, but it is basically just a control somewhat similar to [this one](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=617800), but even simpler (that was the closest example I could find right away, though). Just draw some lines, skip categories that haven't been expanded, draw images, done! Then the two are put in a custom TabControl, which is also easy to make [or find pre-made](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=549147).

Comment: The "custom tab control" is actually what I was asking about. I know I can make one but thought perhaps the one that is used in VS was available from somewhere. Thanks.